# Show and Hide values with jquery change function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to Show() and Hide() the display with respect to the click of the radiobuttonlist.

I have set an attribute keep-customization="1" which is set in table tag.

Code which i wrote is:

```
 $("keep-customization").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked").val() == "")
    {
        example(".textgrid").has("input[keep-current-customization='false']").show();
    }
    else {
        example(".textgrid").has("input[keep-current-customization='false']").hide();
    }
});
```

my Source that looks on the page for the radiobuttonlist is:

#### Keep Your Current Phone Number (Required)

```
                    <div class="desc">
                         Will you be keeping your current phone number?</div>
                    <br />


<div class="textgrid">
                                <div class="feildset1">
                                    <span id="rptCustomization_rptItems_6_ctl00_0" style="display:none;"><strong style="color:Red;">Required.</strong></span><table id="rptCustomization_rptItems_6_ctrl_0" keep-customization="1">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="rptCustomization_rptItems_6_ctrl_0_0_0" type="radio" name="rptCustomization$ctl06$rptItems$ctl00$ctrl" value="43" /><label for="rptCustomization_rptItems_6_ctrl_0_0_0">Y</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="rptCustomization_rptItems_6_ctrl_0_1_0" type="radio" name="rptCustomization$ctl06$rptItems$ctl00$ctrl" value="44" /><label for="rptCustomization_rptItems_6_ctrl_0_1_0">N</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

The div that will show and hide respective on the change of the radiobuttonlist is:

```
<div class="textgrid">
                                <div class="feildset1">
                                    Account holders name on your current phone bill?: </br><input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl00$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_0" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="textgrid">
                                <div class="feildset1">
                                    Current phone company you have?: </br><input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl01$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_1" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="textgrid">
                                <div class="feildset1">
                                    What is the account # with your current provider?: </br><input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl02$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_2" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="textgrid">
                                <div class="feildset1">
                                    What is the PIN/access code for current provider?: </br><input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl03$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_3" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="textgrid">
                                <div class="feildset1">
                                    What are the two nearest cross streets?: </br><input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl04$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_4" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
                                    <br />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create your own html attributes like "keep-customization". Also you cannot handle change event of table because it doesn't exist.

**Try to change it for the class. And bind event to radio buttons.**

Comment: i created it on serverside to differentiate it with others as it is a generic form

Comment: But jQuery cannot handle it.

Comment: @AbidAli, If want to create custom attributes prefix them with `data-`, I think jQuery will support that

Comment: @Satpal `data-` attributes are from HTML5, but there are using for collect some data not for using as selector. Using data attributes simply as selector isn't possible.

Comment: then they will not be usefull in my case then @Satpal.. what you say?